# Using regular definitions in PLY

Tags: python, compiler-construction, lexer, ply

When I use the following code snippet:-

```
t_ASD = r'(a|aa*)'
```

On input `aaaaaaaa` The output comes out to be:-

```
LexToken(ID,'aaaaaaaa',1,0)
```

Which is expected.
But when the same input is run on this code:-

```
ASD = r'(a|aa*)'
@TOKEN(ASD)
def t_ASD(t):
    return t
```

The output comes out to be

```
LexToken(ASD,'a',1,0)
LexToken(ASD,'a',1,1)
LexToken(ASD,'a',1,2)
LexToken(ASD,'a',1,3)
LexToken(ASD,'a',1,4)
LexToken(ASD,'a',1,5)
LexToken(ASD,'a',1,6)
LexToken(ASD,'a',1,7)
```

What can be the possible reason for this mismatch in output? And how to modify the second code to obtain the output:- `LexToken(ID,'aaaaaaaa',1,0)`

Comment: Why is your pattern not just `a+`?

Comment: @L3viathan that is not the point of the question, the point is that the second snippet should also produce the same output as the first one.

Comment: Right. Does it make a difference though? I could imagine the regex engine seeing the first option of the disjunction and therefore splitting the tokens as seen. But it is still a good question why the behaviour differs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's evident from the output from your first example that the token is being matched by the `ID` rule, not the `ASD` rule. Remember that patterns supplied as functions have priority over patterns supplied as variables. (See the [Ply manual](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6).)

Here's my almost minimal test case, without interaction with other rules, which shows that using a pattern variable has the expected result:

```
import ply.lex as lex
tokens = ['A']
ignore = ' \t\n'
def t_error(t):
    print("Bad char: '%s'" % t.value)
    t.lexer.skip()

t_A = r'(a|aa*)'

lexer = lex.lex()
lexer.input('aaaaaaa')
for token in lexer: print(token)
```

Output (same output with python2):

```
$ python3 lexorder.py 
LexToken(A,'a',1,0)
LexToken(A,'a',1,1)
LexToken(A,'a',1,2)
LexToken(A,'a',1,3)
LexToken(A,'a',1,4)
LexToken(A,'a',1,5)
LexToken(A,'a',1,6)
```

It's the expected result because of the way Python regular expressions work. The Python regex engine does not implement longest-match semantics; it prefers earlier alternatives even if their match is shorter.